# Unable to set component attribute on message received from lightning:empAPI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, platform-event, cometd

I have the following lightning component implemented and when a message is received I can obtain attribute data from the component but when trying to set an attribute it doesn't seem to set it, the view is never updated.

View:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="subscription" type="Object" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="testSet" type="String" access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="testGet" type="String" access="private" default="val" />

    <lightning:empApi aura:id="empApi"/>

    {!v.testSet} will never update

</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        var empApi = component.find('empApi');
        var channel = '/event/Test_Channel__e';
        var replayId = -2;

        empApi.onError(function(message) {
            console.log("Received error ", message);
        });

        empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, function(message) {

            console.log(component.get('v.testGet')); //successful read actual value
            component.set('v.testSet', 'test'); // view is not updated

        }).then(function(value) {
            component.set('v.subscription', value);
        });

    }
})
```

Comment: were you able to sort this out?